# \Cref not working with autonum (but \cref, without the capital letter, works...)

Tags: cross-referencing

Why does the following minimal example does not work?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:hello_world}%
1+1 = 2,
\end{equation}
\Cref{eq:hello_world} will be the subject of this course.

% This alternative works!
% \cref{eq:hello_world} will be the subject of this course.

\end{document}
```

It works if:

- I remove autonum,
- I use `\cref` instead of `\Cref`.

Comment: Maybe §3.3 *Reference commands* of [the `autonum` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/autonum/autonum.pdf) can help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `autonum` patches only `\cref` and not `\Cref`. You can do that manually. See §3.3 *Reference commands* of the [`autonum` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/autonum/autonum.pdf).

> As default the `\ref` and `cleveref`’s `\cref` commands are supported (the latter one only if the `cleveref` package is loaded).

Since `autonum.sty` has

```
\autonum@generatePatchedReferenceCSL{cref}
```

I assume that `\Cref` should be patched the same way.

Furthermore, note that

> Range commands like the `\crefrange` command are not supported at the moment.
>   It’s not completely clear, if this is a good or a bad thing. Please contact the package author if you are interested in this feature.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\autonum@generatePatchedReferenceCSL{Cref}
\makeatother

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:hello_world}%
1+1 = 2,
\end{equation}
\Cref{eq:hello_world} will be the subject of this course.

% This alternative works!
%\cref{eq:hello_world} will be the subject of this course.

\end{document}
```

[image: Equation (1) will be the subject of this course.]

Comment: Thank you!

"By default autonum only pacthes \cref and not \Cref", that's a strange decision...

Comment: @Rastapopoulos I assume the author of `autonum` simply forgot about `\Cref`. I don't think there is a technical reason not to include it by default. I suggest you contact the author about this and put in a feature request to also patch `\Cref`.

Comment: Good idea, I will.

Comment: @Rastapopoulos Did you ever contact @Patrick Häcker, the maintainer of `autonum`? This is a pretty huge bug, in my opinion, and four years later it still remains.